# How to recover files from index

Tags: git

I accidentally erase files.
Fortunately, I have added those to index.
Please tell me how to recover those files to working tree, without commiting.

Comment: Note: in 2020: `git restore -- aFile`. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666522/6309).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

2014: [git `checkout-index`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout-index) will restore deleted files. It will NOT change the content of existing files.
(unless, as commented, using the [`-f/--force` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index#Documentation/git-checkout-index.txt--f))

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) mentions a simpler solution, which can also be used to restore the content of files which existing in the working copy to their last indexed state:

```
git checkout -- the_erased_file
```

But that [can silently overwrite an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961348/6309), so don't make mistake.
(`git checkout-index`, by default, won't overwrite)

---

[2020, Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309): use the [`git restore` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore):

You can specify the [source (index), default is the index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--slttreegt) and [destination (working tree)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--W).

```
git restore -- aFile
```

That will restore the working tree from the index.

```
git restore
```

Comment: @CharlesBailey sure, but I am always a bit weary of `git checkout` for files. See second part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2961348/6309

Comment: Yes, `checkout` can be destructive but it is a user command whereas `checkout-index` is really plumbing.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: plumbing, that is true, but in this case, plumbing seems preferable, no? See this debate: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Best-way-to-check-for-a-dirty-working-tree-tp6465415p6472027.html

Comment: Use `git checkout-index --force` to overwrite existing files.

Comment: @TomHale True, but in 2020, the actual command would be `git restore -- aFile`. See my edited answer.