# What does the command git checkout "." do?

Tags: git

Recently I messed up a commit was told to use this command, I am not 100% what it did, seemed very similar to a hard reset but I am not sure it's the same. I could not find a reference in docs.

I could not find how this [What do git checkouts really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296473/what-do-git-checkouts-really-mean) addressed the question, in the event it does please point me to where it does.

Comment: @CalumHalpin That doesn't seem to answer OP's question.

Comment: With Git 2.23, this will be `git restore .`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345176/6309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a command of the form [`git checkout <pathspec>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

What it does is essentially to throw away uncommitted changes in the working tree: It overwrites all files in the given path (here `.`, the current directory, and all of its contents, recursively) with what is in the "index" (which is the latest commit + all changes added by `git add`, if any).

A hard reset does not just throw away your local changes, it also throws away committed history. `git reset --hard FOO` resets the state of the repository to `FOO` and makes it as if any commit after `FOO` never happened. You rarely need to use this.

Comment: Afaik it would be `git checkout -- .`. `git checkout .` would switch to a branch/tag named "`.`".

Comment: @peterh The `--` is optional.

Comment: @peterh: note that `git checkout x` first tries to treat `x` as a *branch name*. If that succeeds, it means "check out branch `x`". If that fails, `git checkout` tries to treat `x` as a commit specifier (a "commit-ish", in Git terms). If that succeeds, it means "check out the commit specified by `x`"—so if `x` is a *tag*, you get a "detached HEAD". Last, if both of these have failed, it tries to treat `x` as a pathspec, as if you'd entered `git checkout -- x`. So if `.` could be a branch or tag name, this could behave differently; but `.` cannot be a branch or tag name.