# I want to save my work when I introduce a bug and be able to go back to my previous commit. How should I approach this with git?

Tags: git

My log looks something like this with the last 2 commits:

```
commit ABC
TEMP

commit DEF

Working!
```

Something I did after `DEF` broke my code.  I didn’t want to lose the changes, so I made a commit named `TEMP`.  I then did `git checkout DEF -f`, then `git status` told me `HEAD detached at DEF`. When I do a log command, I don’t see my TEMP commit.

What I would like to do is to use `git restore` (or another command) to get each modified file from `ABC`, one by one until I find the culprit file. Then I’d like to delete or “strip” `ABC`.  I’m coming from mercurial where you can delete commits.  I haven’t pushed to my remote repo, because I don’t want the `TEMP/ABC` commit to go the remote repo.

I realize I’m probably doing it “the wrong way”, so how should I handle a situation where I messed something up, and I want to go back to the previous commit but save my changes so I can grab them file by file?  I assume there is a better way than creating a `TEMP` commit as I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not pushed, you can (assuming you don't have any work in progress)

- reset --hard to the working commit
- [list file from your "not working" commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/6309)
- restore them one by one and see when it breaks

That is:

```
git switch master
git reset --hard DEF
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ABC
git restore -s ABC -SW -- afile
```

This uses the [new Git 2.23 (August 2019) `git restore` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309).
And the [new `git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

Comment: I’ll give that a shot when I wake up.  How would you handle this assuming I never made a TEMP commit?  Is this a case for `git stash`?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit The reset (after switch master) will get rid of the TEMP detached HEAD. See the second part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309

Comment: Ok, but what I was asking about is what would be if I didn’t create a TEMP commit.  That is I have a changed working directory and want to save the changes and then test each file.  Is creating a temp commit the way to go, or is there another way of temporarily saving the files?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit Yes, creating a temp commit is a good way to stash more permanently your changes. Then you can follow the same recipe I describe in my answer above.