# Cannot find files in my repository using git

Tags: git

I am trying to reset two files in my repository back to HEAD state using git, but I receive the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'package-lock.json' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I am extremely confused because when I run `git status` the files show up as having been modified, so they're definitely there. I found a blog post that suggests the file tree may have been changed but I haven't changed any file or folder names or positions.

Please advise!

code reproduction:

- `git status` returns `package-lock.json` and `src/react-app-env.d.ts`
- `git reset HEAD package-lock.json src/react-app-env.d.ts` runs with no issue and unstages the two files
- `git checkout HEAD -- src/react-app-env.d.ts package-lock.json` gives the following error:

  ```
  error: pathspec 'src/react-app-env.d.ts' did not match any file(s) known to git.
  error: pathspec 'package-lock.json' did not match any file(s) known to git.
  ```

Comment: Can you please show the exact output of the `git status`, `git reset ...` and `git checkout ...` commands?

Comment: Specifically, did `git status` list `package-lock.json` under "Changes not staged for commit" or under "Untracked files"?

Comment: Have the two files been commited before that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're files haven't been commited in order for the `checkout` command to know at which state to put them when you try to move them to `HEAD`. First commit them and then the two commands will run (keep in mind that they do somewhat different things).

**Side note:** in the new versions of git (git 2.23) there is a new command: `git restore <file>` which discards changes in the working directory and there is also `git restore --staged <file>` which unstaged a file. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508799/how-to-reset-all-files-from-working-directory-but-not-from-staging-area/57066072#57066072).

Comment: @chavoshi no worries, if this did the trick you can mark it as answered :)