# recover files from git repository

Tags: git, github, repository, git-bash, git-pull

```
git status
```

shows some files are deleted

```
deleted:    uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
deleted:    uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
```

Is there a way to recover those files

I tried `git checkout .`
but thats not working

Comment: You snipped too much from the `git status` output but because of the behavior of `git checkout .` we can guess that this one thing you snipped out is that these are "changes to be committed". `git checkout -- .` or `git checkout .` (both mean the same thing) won't work because that copies from the *index*, which is precisely where these two files aren't. You need to `git checkout HEAD -- <path>` as in VonC's answer below; the `HEAD` commit contains these two files. These are "changes to be committed" *because* `HEAD` has the files and the index does not have them.

Answer (score 0):

The recent command [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) is a [new experimental command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) since Git 2.23.

```
git restore --source HEAD uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
# shorter:
git restore -s @ uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
```

You restore from HEAD (not from index).

With the old command:

```
git checkout HEAD -- uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
git checkout @ -- uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg
```

Comment: 2.7? That sounds old ;) Any chance to upgrade to 2.25? If not: `git checkout @ -- uploads/cus/zixk19hldk1.jpg`