# Git started detaching head when viewing any previous commits on a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, git-detached-head

I'm a newer git user so this maybe a dumb question, but all the sudden whenever I checkout any previous commit with something like `git checkout 050aa9f` in my `Development` branch, git immediately detaches the head:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
> git checkout -b
>
> HEAD is now at 050aa9f [Code commit title here]

But when I checkout a commit from another branch such as `master` it doesn't detach the head.

Have I done something to corrupt my tree in some way? How can I find where this started, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you show examples of the commands you're running to check out previous commits from `Development`, and to check out a commit from another branch? Also, is there some reason you have to believe your tree may be corrupted? (e.g. missing or corrupted files, missing history when you run `git log`, or so on)

Comment: When you checkout a specific commit, no matter on which branch the commit is, it always leads to detached HEAD. You can just consider a detached HEAD as a nameless branch. It's not an error. If you find it confusing , always use `git checkout -b temp_foo <commit>` to create a local branch (named `temp_foo` in this case) from the commit. You can remove `temp_foo` with `git branch -D temp_foo` when you think it's time.

Comment: One of the most powerful tools in git's toolbox, actually.

Comment: @DavidZ I've updated my OP to reflect this but to get the results above by typing `git checkout 050aa9f`. I used the word corrupt because it's the closest to what I would think would happen, but what I really mean is, could have I messed something up by the way I'm committing, merging, etc?

Comment: @ElpieKay Are you sure? Because when I checkout my master branch, it does not create a detached head. And I may be wrong but I don't recall checking out a previous commit on the same branch causing the head to detach a few weeks ago.

Comment: @JhonPiper It would still be really helpful to know what command you ran to check out a commit from `master` such that it didn't detach the head.

Comment: @DavidZ Very similarly I have tried both `git checkout master` and `git checkout 5cb9b78` in which I get the same result. (5cb9b78 is the 2nd newest commit on master, so it's one commit behind current)

Comment: @JhonPiper Oh I meant edit it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> whenever I [use] ... `git checkout 050aa9f` ... git immediately detaches the head

That's because this kind of `git checkout` is specifically a request to detach `HEAD`.

*Any* time you use something that is not a *branch name*, but can be resolved to a commit hash ID, `git checkout` will put you in detached-HEAD mode.  But any time you use something that *is* a branch name, `git checkout` will put you in the normal mode.  (Git does not call this "attached-HEAD" mode but that's the obvious right name for the mode.)

There are several tricky bits here, some of which are partly helped out by using the new (in Git 2.23 and later) `git switch` command as [VonC recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61744751/1256452).  I'll go through them here, but remember that some of this is Advanced Git and you're not expected to know all of it right away.

- Git can *create a new branch*, then check that branch out by name, resulting in an attached HEAD.
- You can use `--detach` with a branch name to force Git to enter detached HEAD mode even if you provide a branch name.
- Using the `-b` option, Git will always try to create a new branch name (and then attach to it).  This can fail in several cases, though I won't go into any details here.
- Using the `--track` option, you can name a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/develop` and Git will use that name to figure out which branch name to create.  The name Git picks here is formed by stripping off the remote part, so running `git checkout --track origin/develop` is roughly the same as running `git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop`.  I say *roughly* the same because additional options can modify this behavior.
- The `git checkout` command itself implements what has, in Git 2.23 and later, been split into two separate commands: `git switch`, and `git restore`.  In some cases, when you expect `git checkout` to do what I am about to describe, Git will discover that you have a *file or folder* named `dev` and implement what is now split out as `git restore`, instead of what is now `git switch`.  This is ... not a good thing, let's just say, and since Git 2.23, `git checkout` now *tells* you that it wasn't sure what you meant here, and doesn't just do the *wrong* thing.
- Giving the name of a branch that does not exist, but that can be created, sometimes results in creating that branch.  For instance, if you *do not yet have* a branch named `dev`, but do have an `origin/dev`, and you run `git checkout dev`, you might expect Git to say: *Huh ... there's no **branch** named `dev` and no file-or-folder named `dev`.  I can't turn that into a branch name, so I'll just quit with an error.*  But that's not what happens.  Instead, Git says to itself: *Huh, there's no **branch** named `dev`, and no file-or-folder named that either.  But there is an `origin/dev`.  I'll bet you wanted me to **create** a branch named `dev`, as if you had run `git checkout --track origin/dev`.*  And then it does that.

---

It's worth describing exactly what goes wrong with the old `git checkout` here, that doesn't with the new `git switch` / `git restore` split.  (And, as I mentioned, `git checkout` itself has been made smarter so that it doesn't just blindly do the wrong thing now—but with Git versions older than 2.23, watch out!)  The two "kinds" of `git checkout` are:

- The one that switches branches.  This is a non-destructive command: if you have uncommitted work, `git checkout` *may* let you switch branches, but it will only do that if none of your uncommitted work will be destroyed in the process.  (This is complicated.  Don't look at it yet, but [this question is all about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)

  In Git 2.23, you can use `git switch` to do this command.  You can still use `git checkout`, too.
- The one that clobbers your uncommitted work.  This is a destructive command!  Suppose you've been editing some files and you have decided that your attempt to do something useful has been fruitless, and should now be utterly, irrevocably destroyed.  You'd like to put things back to the way they were—at least, for one specific file, and maybe for several files.

  In Git 2.23, you can use `git restore` to do this command, but in every version of Git, you can use `git checkout` here too.

This means one kind of `git checkout` is entirely safe: it never wrecks in-progress work.  The other kind of `git checkout` is quite dangerous: you're telling Git *please wipe out my in-progress work, irretrievably.*

This is the danger I mentioned above.  Suppose you have a bunch of files in a folder named `dev`, *and* a remote-tracking name `origin/dev`, but you *do not yet have a branch named `dev`*.  If you run:

```
git checkout dev
```

expecting Git to create a branch named `dev` now based on `origin/dev`, you get a nasty surprise: Git (before 2.23) wipes out any work you've done on the `dev/*` files instead.

---

(There are even more things that `git checkout` can do, all of which are now part of the split-out commands.  I've left these out to keep this answer short.  Well, short*er*, anyway.)

Comment: Does `git checkout` have any use at all in git 2.23 or newer then?

Comment: @JhonPiper: It's still around so that existing scripts, and existing programmer brains, don't have to change. I still use it out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

> Because when I checkout my master branch, it does not create a detached head

First, make sure to [use `git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), that way you are sure to deal with branch or commits (checkout deals also with files, now better served with [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309))

Second, when you checkout master, you are switching to an indirect reference to a branch HEAD commit.
Indirect because:

- `.git/HEAD` will include "`refs/heads/master`
- `.git/refs/heads/master` will include the actual SHA1

As opposed to checkout/switch a commit, and `.git/HEAD` including the SHA1 directly (no branch indirection)

That is why I like the new [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command: as I explain in "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)", it expects by default a branch, not a commit. It is harder to end up with an unwanted/unexpected detached HEAD.