# HOW TO - Move git to another computer

Tags: git

I have a little issue with git. I have on my main computer the original repo, where I started the development of the git repo

I have a new computer and now I want to move the "original repo" (local one) to the new one, and continue working on it and push new modifications to git.

For now, I copy/paste the entire folder (with `.git` folder) but I can't do nothing. What are the steps to do ?

Comment: Why not just clone to your new computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do nothing"?

Comment: When you say "I can't do nothing", what did you *try*?

Answer (score 4):

> I copy/paste the entire folder (with .git folder) but I can't do nothing.

That should be enough (assuming indeed that Git is installed): if you have copied said `.git/` in `/path/to/repo`, you should be able to restore everything with the new [`git restore` commad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) (2.23+)

```
git restore -s@ -W -- .
```

Comment: assuming you installed git onto the new machine. Making the point as this is one of the greatest misconceptions about git around.

Comment: @DaemonPainter good point indeed.