# Update Apache Server with Git Pull

Tags: git, apache

My current set up is as follows:

- I have a laptop in which I like to write my website's code
- I have a raspberry pi running Apache which will serve my website's code as long as it is in `/var/www/html`
- I have clone a repository of my website onto the raspberry pi in Directory A.

I want to create a git hook so that when I pull my code the code updates in `/var/www/html`

I have tried creating both a `post-merge` and `post-receive` hook using the following code:

`#!/bin/bash git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=DIRECTORY A`

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: In which repository do you pull the code? In which repository do you install the hooks?

Comment: I would pull the code on the server (ie the raspberry pi) and I installed the hooks on the server. If there is a different way, I would be happy to do that as well. I am very much a noob with this.

Answer (score 0):

The full command would be, in a post-receive hook:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=DIRECTORYA restore -- .
                                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Assuming you have a [Git 2.23+, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309), or, if not:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=DIRECTORYA checkout -- .
```