# Remote path revert changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

When ever I push my changes to remote path from my local. (Remote path is my dev server). All my changes are showing as unstaged and remove all of my changes. and my changes does not exists on my dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your remote path is not one for a checked out repository, but for a bare repository (`xxx.git`, with only git database files, and not `xxx/.git`, with checked out files in it)

While you can [technically push to a non-bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309), a [post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62989497/6309) is safer to restore your files on your dev server where you want them to be.