# Git revert and reset : Files in the repository are not getting rolled back

Tags: github, github-actions

I want my entire repository to roll back to a certain previous commit (that is 20 commits behind my latest commit).

I tried using `git reset --hard <commit#>`  and `git revert <commit#>`

Both the git commands run successfully with the message - `Head is now at <commithead>`

But then when I see the code in my repo, I can still see the edits I made in my latest commits. How can I remove all the edits after the particular commit I am reverting to?

Am I missing out on some step here?

Comment: `git revert` is not ideal in this situation as it will create extra commits,unless your repo is being used by others  . `git reset --HARD ` should be enough

Comment: I see. But the problem is that I don't see the changes being reflected in my repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `git reset --hard`, use to be sure the [`git restore` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)

```
cd /path/to/repository
git restore -- .
```

That should restore (as its name implies) the working tree with what is in HEAD (and you just reset HEAD to the right commit)