# Git pull not populating my local folder with remote repo?

Tags: git, merge, fetch, bitbucket, pull

I am trying to pull the code from a remote branch to a local folder on my machine. I created a git repo and am now on the branch that I want to be get code from.

```
AAA@AAA-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/BBB/CCC$ git branch
  dev-master
* feature/multi-pouch_2021
```

My folder is completely empty but when I run a git pull it says already up to date so I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
AAA@AAA-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/BBB/CCC$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

I have also tried `git pull origin feature/multi-pouch_2021` (the branch I want) but nothing populates my folder with the files.

Comment: Are you sure that the branch actually contains something ? How did you check that ?

Comment: Yes, on bitbucket I can see all of the files for each branch @GaëlJ

Comment: And what does your `git status` says?

Comment: Your branch is up to date with 'feature/multi-pouch_2021' when there is nothing in the folder @GaëlJ

Comment: Then i'm pretty sure you're not looking at the good branch: this one is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try first a [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) (assuming [Git 2.23+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309))

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git restore -- .
```

Note the `--` (to separate options from arguments) and '`.`' for restoring everything from current path.

Then see if the folder is still empty.

Comment: I tried the git restore -- . and nothing happend. The files were not restored.

Comment: For testing, can you do, in a separate folder, a git clone -b feature/multi... https://url/repo

Comment: Do you want me to git init, etc. or just run the git clone command? @VonC

Comment: Just git clone, but in a new empty folder, outside of your current clone. Also, what is your version of git?