# How to git checkout a file on another branch using "restore" instead?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to rebuild my git workflow by using `restore` instead of the old `checkout`. I knew that restore can **undo** my previous work (on my branch). But what if I want to checkout a file from another branch? The `checkout` version is quite simple,

```
git checkout main -- my-file
```

**Can I do the same thing with `restore` command?**

My further question is: **should I totally move from `checkout` to `switch` and `restore`** since they already split some features apart, like:

```
git checkout -b new-branch   ===>   git switch -c new-branch
git checkout -- my-file      ===>   git restore -- my-file
```

I mean if I can also checkout a file from another branch using `restore`, there's almost no need of `checkout` in simple daily use.

Feel free to redirect this question to other similar one if any.

Comment: This comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the intention *is* to replace `git checkout` with `git restore` and `git switch` as appropriate.

Where `git checkout` takes two positional arguments to specify the branch and a file within that branch, `git restore` uses the `--source` argument to specify the "tree" (could be a branch, tag, commit, etc) from which to take the file given as a positional argument.

```
# git checkout dev my-file
git restore --source dev my-file
```

Comment: It works, thx. So do you recommend to use `restore` and `switch` to replace the old `checkout` and `reset`, I mean TOTALLY?

Comment: `reset` is still used to change what a branch head refers to, independent of what `checkout`, `restore`, and `switch` do. I *try* to use `restore` and `switch` in place of `checkout`, and for my needs, they've been sufficient. I would stick with `checkout` in a script until `restore`/`switch` are no longer documented as experimental, but for command-line use, you can probably use them exclusively.

Comment: Thanks @chepner , it's quite helpful!

Comment: Note that Junio Hamano, at least, still seems rather resistant to, um, "encouraging" use of separate restore and switch. Or that's my reading of messages on the Git mailing list. :-) I'm pretty firmly in the switch-to-switch camp myself, but obviously opinions vary.

Comment: @torek I would be interested in a reference (link) to illustrate this resistance. And I am curious to see if https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.1095.git.1639117329.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/#u will go through (new option to the old checkout command)

Comment: @VonC: I'm afraid that's going to be very hard for me to find. It's a *feeling*, not an outright statement.

Comment: @torek OK. That is reassuring. I will keep promoting switch/restore over the obsolete and confusing checkout command.