# How git checkout old_branch * within a subdirectory work?

Tags: git, unix, git-branch, git-checkout

I am new to git and recently get confused about the code below. My question are,

- Why `git branch new_branch` will copy the current `release_branch`?
- After checkout the new branch, why we could enter a sub directory and just re-checkout an old branch to bring in the old script?
- Why the last checkout line (for old branch) will only restore the files in this subdirectory instead of bringing all scripts or switching to the old branch?

```
# Say pwd is /home/ab/
git checkout -f $RELEASE_BRANCH
git branch $NEW_REPAIR_BRANCH
git checkout $NEW_REPAIR_BRANCH
cd /home/ab/cd/ef/
rm -r *
git checkout $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH *
```

Is there anyone could help me explain the logic? Much appreciate! Btw, I believe they should be able to be simplified as well!

Comment: You might want to stop using `git checkout` entirely: consider using the two commands `git switch` and `git restore` instead. You will need Git version 2.23 or later. Moving to the new commands may help you understand why `git checkout` is so puzzling: it's actually two separate commands that are just spelled the same!

Comment: @torek Agree, the code I attached is pretty old. Will try to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why git branch new_branch will copy the current release_branch?

`git branch new_branch` is short for `git branch new_branch HEAD`. It creates `new_branch` from the current HEAD. If `HEAD` points to `release_branch`, then it's equivalent to `git branch new_branch release_branch`.

> After checkout the new branch, why we could enter a sub directory and
> just re-checkout an old branch to bring in the old script?
>
> Why the last checkout line (for old branch) will only restore the
> files in this subdirectory instead of bringing all scripts or
> switching to the old branch?

`git checkout $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH` means "to checkout $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH". But `git checkout $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH *` is quite different. It does not switch the branch at all. `*` means all files and directories under the current folder. The files and directories whose names start with a dot are excluded, like `.git` and `.gitignore`.

```
# enter /home/ab/cd/ef
cd /home/ab/cd/ef/

# remove all files and directories under /home/ab/cd/ef/
# files like `.gitignore` and folders like `.git` are not removed
rm -r *
```

`git checkout $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH *` updates the files with their versions in `OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH`. Imagine that it creates a file with its content recorded in `OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH` . As `*` refers to the entries under the current directory only, the files in its parent directories and sibling directories are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Anything done with git checkout/git branch could be done with the [new `git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) command ([man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)), as well as [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) (for file-based operations: [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--slttreegt)).

```
git switch -c $NEW_REPAIR_BRANCH $RELEASE_BRANCH
git restore --source $OLD_REPAIR_BRANCH
```

That way, you clearly distinguish the branch switches from the files restore steps.
And you avoid '`*`', which depends on the underlying shell to be interpreted and expanded.