# How to git reset --hard only deleted files and keep existing files intact?

Tags: git, file-recovery

Let's say I have files `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in my repo. All of them has been modified from the last commit, but not staged yet. Due to a syncing bug, `A` and `B` are deleted. I understand that changes in them are gone, but at least I want to recover them from the last commit. Is there a way to `git reset --hard` only deleted files while keeping existing files intact? Assuming there are many of them, so I can't `git checkout` individual files or folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `git reset --hard`, a [`git ls-files -d`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--d) might help (coupled with [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309), if you are using Git 2.23+):

```bash
git ls-files --deleted | xargs -I {} git restore --source=HEAD -- {}

# For older Git, pre 2.23, before Q3 2019:
git ls-files --deleted | xargs -I {} git checkout HEAD -- {}
```

---

> it seems that `git ls-files` only reads files from the working tree and stage?
> What about a specific commit?

For listing deleted files from a given commit, you would use `git log` with a [`diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203), and an [empty format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

```bash
git log --diff-filter=D --first-parent --pretty=format: --name-only -1 <commit>
```

In your case, to restore those files from that commit:

```bash
git log --diff-filter=D --first-parent --pretty=format: --name-only -1 <commit> | \
    xargs -I {} git restore --source=<commit> -- {}
```

Or, as [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376334/how-to-git-reset-hard-only-deleted-files-and-keep-existing-files-intact/77376465#comment136426556_77376465), using the same [`diff-filter` with `git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

```bash
git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only <commit>~ <commit> | \
    xargs -I {} git restore --source=<commit> -- {}
```

---

> if I need to list all the files having been deleted in the last 5 commits, what should I do?

```bash
git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only @~5
```

Comment: it seems that `git ls-files` only reads files from the working tree and stage? What about a specific commit?

Comment: @Ooker True. I have edited the answer to include a way to restore deleted files from a past commit. This time, `git log` is used, not `git ls-files`.

Comment: @LeGEC It would, yes, thank you for the suggestion. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I usually use `git log` to, at least, see which commits have deleted files. Plus, the `git log -1 <commit>` (one commit parameter) avoids the `diff <commit>~ <commit>` (two commit parameters).

Comment: @LeGEC "What about a specific commit?": I interpret that as "restoring deleted files for... a specific commit".

Comment: if I need to list all the files having been deleted in the last 5 commits, what should I do?

Comment: @Ooker I have edited the answer to address your comment. And I have amended the `git log` part, by adding the [`--first-parent` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---first-parent) (in case someone would use it for more than one commit).

Comment: hmm, why does for some repos it yield this error `fatal: ambiguous argument '@~5': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`, while for others repos it work fine?

Comment: @Ooker Possibly because the branch you are using does have less than 5 commits.

Comment: I see. If I want to compare to a remote, what should I do?

Comment: @Ooker You can use a remote reference, like `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only origin/main~5 origin/main`, in order to visualize files deleted in the last 5 commits of the remote `origin/main` branch