# git alias to rename existing command

Tags: git

I'm loosing too much work working on both svn and git repositories at work. And i'm not the only one: [Get back the changes after accidental checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout)

I wanted to rename/overload the checkout command with an alias.

basically, `checkout` would just show me a diff of what i'm losing (or curse at myself, or run the [`sl` command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPMd2dsSVR0) :D )

and then i'd have the `revert` to alias to do the real checkout command.

Is the first step possible? to alias something over the original command? or will `checkout` always trigger the checkout command? I basically want to lock me out of checkout.

Bonus points if i can change the behaviour only when `git checkout <file>` and not on `git checkout <branch/tag/ref>`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to make a wrapper for the command git itself (and reference that wrapper first in the PATH environment variable)

The wrapper could check:

- what command is run (checkout or not)
- what parameter is used (a file or not)

Comment: of course, a shell alias!. that is a nice solution. and should have been the most obvious :) thanks! ...maybe i can even coerce it to handle files vs non files based on the argument..