# Git: how to revert the local edit before using git checkout <old-revision> <file>?

Tags: git

Say I have a file `file.txt`, 
I've committed some revisions and now I've edited it in my working copy, I didn't stage or commit these edits.

Then I use `git checkout <an-old-revision> file.txt`, the `file.txt` goes back to an old commit.
Now I regret my checkout, how do I bring my edits back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get back the changes after accidental checkout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With git you cannot get these local changes back because you never committed/added or stashed them. If you use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea then the first thing i would check is if you can recover your changes via the local history of the file. If you do not use an IDE then a backup would be helpful.

Comment: Is there any hack to avoid this scenario from happening?

Comment: Normally git aborts a checkout operation if you have uncommited local changes that would get lost. You will see an error message: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:`

Comment: the change is not staged and I didn't see the warning, my git version is "git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)"

Comment: You didn't see that error because you didn't checkout a branch. Rather you told git to reset the file.txt contents to the specific revision. As you never told git about a file change (`add`, `stash`, `commit`) it will happily overwrite file contents when running `git checkout <committish> <file>`, making you lose your edits.