# Get working directory changes back

Tags: git

We are two guys in a team. One of us unfortunately could not adapt usage of Git. Periodically I move his changes to our release version. Yesterday, I had a trouble about his changes at working directory. When I typed `git checkout -b new_branch` our all working directory changes of previous branch were gone. Now, is there any way to undo his working directory changes at previous branch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28360171/6309 wouldn't help?

Comment: Yes,  I have examined it, however it cannot be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your English is really hard to understand. From what I understood you are talking about uncommitted changes.

Uncommitted changes are always troublesome. Before doing anything important with git, check your uncommitted changes: If they are good, commit them. If they are bad, discard them.

If you have important changes and do not commit them, git does not know about it and will therefore not be able to help you with that.

Comment: Michas many thanks for your all efforts about editing my message. While people are under the risk, they can make mistakes. Spelling mistakes are also one of them. Especially you write in a language does not belong to you. Anyway... We use Adobe Brackets. I am also looking whether a local history property is avaliable or not in this IDE. Many thanks again.