# "git checkout ../../..": what does it mean

Tags: git

I accidentally type

```
git checkout ../../..
```

when I actually meant

```
cd ../../..
```

I realize all my uncommitted changes are gone. Is there anyway I can recover them?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but unless you did and "add" or a "stash", you can't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get back the changes after accidental checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout)

Answer (score 1):

If you used `git checkout path` and it overwrote uncommitted changes, those changes are generally gone without the ability to recover (though your OS may offer some non-Git method, e.g., Time Machine on OS X).  See also [Get back the changes after accidental checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2961240/1256452)

Your subject line asks what:

```
git checkout ../../..
```

means.  It tells Git that Git should check out the directory `../../..` from the current commit, i.e., from whatever sub-sub-sub-directory you are in—such as `a/b/c/` if your layout includes a top level directory `a`, subdirectory `b` within `a`, and subdirectory `c` within `b`.  In thiat particular case—climbing up three levels, from a directory three levels down—you would arrive at your top level directory, so this would check out (extract) every file that is in the index, overwriting the work-tree versions.

If you were four levels down—e.g., in `a/b/c/d/`—this would tell Git to overwrite the work-tree copy of every file in `a/` from the index copy.