# How to revert "git checkout --" to get local changes back

Tags: git, git-checkout, revert

By mistake I ran `git checkout --` and all local changes are gone. I can't see anything when running `git log`. How can I get all local changes back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get back the changes after accidental checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout)

Answer (score 1):

From what I’m aware of, calling `git checkout — <file>` will **permanently** discard local changes on that file, meaning you won’t be able to retrieve it.

However, if your work may be on a separate IDE or tool it may have revision histories so you could possible retrieve it from there, however I’m unsure if it’s possible still.

Git has a dedicated page to this question: [how to undo changes with GIT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/numerous_undo_possibilities_in_git/)