# Can I rollback "git checkout ."？

Tags: git

For some bug,I execute "git checkout .".It revert all files modified.Can I rollback the operation? I just just revert the specified file modified.I lost the other files modified. What I can do to solved the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+checkout

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added the working directory changes to index. Due to this, when you run below command,

```
git checkout . #. is pathspec, which corresponding to current directory
```

The whole contents of current directory are replaced by index. Your working changes are lost. Unless, you have some other regular backup mechanism, you cannot recover these lost files.

The [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) talks about this:

> git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=] []
> [--] …​
>
> git checkout
> [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=] []
> --pathspec-from-file= [--pathspec-file-nul]
>
> Overwrite the contents of the files that match the pathspec. When the
>  (most often a commit) is not given, overwrite working tree
> with the contents in the index. When the  is given,
> overwrite both the index and the working tree with the contents at the
> .

As a general best practice, don't run git checkout command against dirty working directory. add the changes to index and then go with git checkout.
[Read more about this problem and other best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961240/get-back-the-changes-after-accidental-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you did, or how you did it... but "don't panic":

> https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting
>
> **Checkout old commits**
>
> Since this has the potential to overwrite local changes, Git forces
>   you to commit or stash any changes in the working directory that will
>   be lost during the checkout operation. Unlike git reset , git checkout
>   doesn't move any branches around.

So the first thing you want to do is check and see if you've "lost" any uncommitted changes.  In all likelihood - you haven't.

But if worse comes to worst - and to answer your question - No, you can't "undo" a checkout