# Discard changes in one single line

Tags: git

I've noticed that in Tower (Git client for the Mac) the user can discard changes even line by line. I wonder how could this be done using the command line? or maybe is something special of Tower?

I frequently find myself in this case:

```
@@ -391,7 +392,7 @@ extern BOOL validateReceiptAtPath(NSString *path);

       NSURL *url = [self fileURL];
        if (url != nil) {
                NSRect readFrame = [self _readPreferenceOfFileAtURL:url];
-               
+
                for (NSScreen * screen in [NSScreen screens]) {
                        NSRect screenVisibleRect = [screen visibleFrame];
                        ...
```

See how I have one `+` and one `-`  ? I would like to discard it so my commit has the minimum changes (hence less possibilities of conflicts and easier review)

:)

Comment: I can understand not wanting them for a review, but I would still recommend checking in whitespace corrections like that so your code base will improve.  If they really bug you that much, there's probably a setting in your editor to avoid doing it in the first place (something like "remove whitespace at end of line").

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is called **interactive staging** and can be done using `git add -i` or `git add -p`. See the [git-add manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html), [pro git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) and the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_adding.html) for more information.

EDIT:

To interactively unstage a file, you can use:

```
git checkout -p HEAD
```

Also see this SO question: [Undo part of unstaged changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981830/undo-part-of-unstaged-changes-in-git)

Comment: it's incredible that i've never yet used `git checkout -p <my file>`.  thanks for leading me to this.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the OP's question. Just wanted to point something out... This is a great answer if you're trying to undo any changes; however, I'd take caution with this. This will undo the changes in your local file (within hunks, of course). If you intended to **unstage**, but keep the changes in your local file, use [Robert Siemer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891603/3993154) instead.

Answer (score 7):

To undo hunks use

```
git reset --patch
```

It’s a very hidden feature. You can *stage* hunk by hunk with `git add --interactive`, but you can’t *unstage* this way. `git add` also features the option `--patch` which is like `--interactive`, but goes directly to the “patch” menu point (otherwise you have to hit <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

`git reset` does not mirror the `--interactive` option, but has `--patch`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git add -e` to edit your file right before staging it.

Answer (score 1):

To interactively unstage a file use:

```
git add -i
```

then you will get following options -

```
*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
```

Use 3rd option `revert` to unstage files

Read more here - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging